# Collapsing Content - Javascript CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for help in modifying the code I have cobbled together to expand a panel to show full details for an item.

The code works fine for a single element on the page. However, I want to change it so I can have multiple items listed. However, at present when I add additional panels they do not collapse and expand only the first instance works.

I assume I need to adjust the Javascript in some way so it can link to each unique instance.

I know there are existing packages available from jquery and bootstrap but for reasons I won't go into these are difficult for me to implement so I am hoping someone can help me modify this code to work.

```js
window.onload=function(){
var tagList = document.getElementById('tagList')
var style = window.getComputedStyle(tagList)
var display = String(style.getPropertyValue('display'));
tagList.style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('clearance-item-header').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var tagList = document.getElementById('tagList')
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(tagList)
    var display = String(style.getPropertyValue('display'));
    if (display == 'none') {
       tagList.style.display = 'inline';
       document.getElementById('toggleExpandBtn').textContent = '[-]';
    } else {
       //style.setProperty('height',lineheight*3+'px');
       tagList.style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('toggleExpandBtn').textContent = '[+]';
    }
});
}
```

```css
<style type='text/css'>
    #tagList { overflow: hidden; }
 .clearance-item {border:2px solid #C00;border-radius:4px;background: #FFF; padding:10px; width: 675px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:relative;}
 .clearance-item-image {width:200px; height:100px; float:left; padding-right: 10px;}
 .clearance-item-image img {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 100px;}
 .clearance-item-title {width:450px; float:left;}
 .clearance-item-title h2 {margin-bottom:7px; padding-top: 3px; color:#C00; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;}
 .clearance-item-detail {width:300px; float:left;}
 .clearance-item-detail p {margin-bottom:7px; color:#000; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}
 .clearance-item-price {width:105px; float:left; padding-right: 60px;}
 .clearance-item-price > div {margin-bottom:7px; color:#C00; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:right;}
 #toggleExpandBtn {width: 30px; position:absolute; right: 8px; bottom: 8px; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#C00;  z-index:9999;}
 #clearance-item-header {cursor:pointer;}
 #buylink {width:250px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; float:right; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 10px;}
 .buylink-product select {max-width:200px !important;}
 .clearance-item-content { padding-top:10px; }
 .clearance-item-content h3 { margin-bottom:8px; color:#000; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}
 .clearance-item-content p { margin-bottom:6px; text-align:justify; }
  </style>
```

```html
 <div class="clearance-item">
    <div id="clearance-item-header">
        <div class="clearance-item-image">
         <img src="images/clearance-item.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearance-item-title">
        <h2>Product Full Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="clearance-item-detail">
            <p>Condition: New/Used/Other</p>
            <p>Location: Brighton</p>
        </div>   
        <div class="clearance-item-price">
            <p>£999.99</p>
        </div>
        <div id="toggleExpandBtn">[+]</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>  
    </div>
    <div id='tagList'>
      <div class="clearance-item-content">
        <h3>Product Name</h3>
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
       </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
    </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You say

> at present when I add additional panels they do not collapse and expand only the first instance works

Could you provide some code with an additional panel? Without seeing your code it is difficult to tell, although I would suggest you make sure that each of the panels and buttons has unique ids. Otherwise, you would get the result you are experiencing from js.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Figured it out. Changed the styling id's to classes and got the javascript to dynamically assign unique id's to each instance as well as adding click event to the header div. Then used this.getAttribute("id") to get the id of the instance of the header that was clicked. Used that to set display to inline or none for the associated content.

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var headerclassname = document.getElementsByClassName("item-header");
  for(var i=0;i<headerclassname.length;i++){
   headerclassname[i].addEventListener('click', toggleContent, false);
   headerclassname[i].id = 'item-header-' + i;
  }
  
  var contentclassname = document.getElementsByClassName("item-content");
  for(var x=0;x<contentclassname.length;x++){
   contentclassname[x].style.display = 'none';
   contentclassname[x].id = 'item-content-' + x;
  }
  
  var toggleclassname = document.getElementsByClassName("item-toggle");
  for(var y=0;y<contentclassname.length;y++){
   toggleclassname[y].id = 'item-toggle-' + y;
  }
 }
 
 var toggleContent = function() {
  var headerid = this.getAttribute("id");
  var contentid = headerid.replace("item-header-", "item-content-"); 
  var toggleid = headerid.replace("item-header-", "item-toggle-"); 
     var displayvalue = document.getElementById(contentid).style.display;

  if (displayvalue == 'none') {
     document.getElementById(contentid).style.display  = 'inline';
     document.getElementById(toggleid).textContent = '[-]';
  } else {
     document.getElementById(contentid).style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById(toggleid).textContent = '[+]';
  }
 }
```

```css
<style type='text/css'>
    .item-content { overflow: hidden; }
 .item {border:2px solid #C00;border-radius:4px;background: #FFF; padding:10px; width: 675px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:relative;}
 .item-image {width:200px; height:100px; float:left; padding-right: 10px;}
 .item-image img {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 100px;}
 .item-title {width:450px; float:left;}
 .item-title h2 {margin-bottom:7px; padding-top: 3px; color:#C00; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;}
 .item-detail {width:300px; float:left;}
 .item-detail p {margin-bottom:7px; color:#000; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}
 .item-price {width:105px; float:left; padding-right: 60px;}
 .item-price > div {margin-bottom:7px; color:#C00; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:right;}
 .item-toggle {width: 30px; position:absolute; right: 8px; bottom: 8px; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; color:#C00;  z-index:9999;}
 .item-header {cursor:pointer;}
 #buylink {width:250px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; float:right; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 10px;}
 .buylink-product select {max-width:200px !important;}
 .item-description { padding-top:10px; }
 .item-description h3 { margin-bottom:8px; color:#000; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}
 .item-description p { margin-bottom:6px; text-align:justify; }
  </style>
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-header">
        <div class="item-image">
         <img src="image.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
        <h2>Item Title Here</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item-detail">
            <p>Condition: New</p>
            <p>Location: Brighton</p>
        </div>   
        <div class="item-price">
            <p>£100.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-toggle">[+]</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div id="buylink">
            <?PHP processWebCodes("Type: BuyLink
                                  Layout: Combined
                                  Product: 1200811
                                  1200811-AllVariants: True");?>
        </div>
      <div class="item-description">
        <h3>Sub Title Here</h3>
          <p>Detailed Description Here</p>
            
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
       </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
    </div>   
</div>
```